# Android: How to get context of calling activity in an IntentService?

Tags: android, intentservice

If I call

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ReadingActivity.this, AdService.class);
startService(intent);
```

from within the `onCreate` method of `MyActivity` class, how do I get access to `MyActivity.this` from inside the `onHandleIntent()` method of the `IntentService` class

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ((BookLib) getApplication()).createAd(I need to pass the calling activities context here);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> how do I get access to MyActivity.this from inside the onHandleIntent method of the IntentService class

You don't.

Move `createAd()` into the activity. If time is an issue, use an `AsyncTask` rather than an `IntentService`.

An `IntentService` is mostly for cases where you want work to go on decoupled from *any* activity (e.g., a file download that should continue even if the user leaves your UI to go on to do something else).

Comment: Thank you. Guess I need to go research AsyncTask

Comment: This answer is a good advice in this case---hammer and nail story. Yet, in case you need access the context (perhaps an instance of activity), `getApplicationContext()` is [available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350943/obtaining-context-for-geolocation-within-an-intentservice). I think that even from an `IntentService`, there are cases where it makes sense. For example to get system services (e.g. `context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);`).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like you're trying to do bi-directional communication with your `Activity` and `Service`. Instead of sending an `Intent` to your service, consider [binding](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder) to it instead.

EDIT: Responding to CommonsWare's comments:

Where is the problem with binding to an `IntentService`? I've shipped apps that work just fine that contain a bound `IntentService`. You've provided no evidence to back up your claim.

From [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle):

> A service can be both started and have connections bound to it. In
>   such a case, the system will keep the service running as long as
>   either it is started or there are one or more connections to it with
>   the `Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE` flag. Once neither of these situations
>   hold, the service's `onDestroy()` method is called and the service is
>   effectively terminated. All cleanup (stopping threads, unregistering
>   receivers) should be complete upon returning from `onDestroy()`.

The docs clearly indicate that the system supports simultaneous binding and starting. Using an `IntentService` over a regular `Service` doesn't change this. Even if you explicitly stop the service after processing an `Intent`, Android leaves it running as long as something is still bound to it.

Besides, depending on what OP is trying to do, `IntentService` might no longer be necessary.

Comment: Binding and `IntentServices` do not go together well. Binding to regular services is fine, and sending commands to `IntentServices` (via `startService()`) is fine.

Comment: "Where is the problem with binding to an IntentService?" -- at best, it will only work if you bind first, before calling `startService()`. Otherwise, you get race conditions where `onHandleIntent()` completes before the binding occurs, causing the first `IntentService` instance to be destroyed (via `stopSelf()`) and the binding to occur on the second one. IMHO, if you think you want to bind to an `IntentService`, you really should bind to a regular `Service` and just manage your own background thread.