# Obtaining Context for Geolocation within an IntentService

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating an Android Class library that makes calls to an internal REST API and also utilizes Android's Geocoder class (specifically getFromLocation()) which requires Context.  I was planning on making the library an IntentService to allow for it to be run asynchronously, but I can't figure out how to handle Context (the GeoLoc call is in a separate class that is part of the library that the IntentService calls).

My question is, how do I obtain context necessary to instantiate android.location.Geocoder from within an IntentService?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every `Service` **is** a `Context`. You can use `this` or `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: I assume I call this in the Intent Service and pass it to my object?

Comment: Yes! Call it inside your IntentService.

Comment: When you want to use SystemService within onHandleIntent, you cannot call getSystemService on 'this' context and should always use 'getApplicationContext()' to access getSystemService().

Answer (score 0):

[IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) Inherits [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), and Service Inherits Context.

You are free to use "this" as Context whenever you needs it inside your IntentService.